# Raspberry Pi 3 onboard Wifi only slow bitrates

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B that runs Debian 8.0. So far I didn't install anything and only run raspi-config.

I want to use the onboard Wifi card, and I can connect to my 2.4Ghz Wifi, but none of the 5Ghz ones.

`iwlist wlan0 scanning` just doesn't show them up. Also, the bitrates are only max 54Mb/s:

```
Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
```

Do I have to enable something?

Answer (score 5):

The Raspberry Pi 3 B only has 2.4GHz wireless, not 5GHz.

Specs [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3-specs-benchmarks/).

Comment: Ok so 54 Mb/s will be the fastest possible?

Comment: I couldn't work out whether that was a limitation. Apparently 802.11n goes "up to" 600Mb/s but I couldn't easily find more detail.

Comment: My bad - sorry. I thought 802.11n is 5Ghz only. But the RPi should still support more than 54Mb/s, right?

Comment: @Daniel No, all 802.11g speeds above 54Mb/s(the standard-defined limit) are wireless hardware venndor-brew extensions, like D-Link 108Mbit/s SuperG. And they can work **only if supported and implemented in hardware by both sides**

Answer (score 1):

5ghz is 802.11a. Max select-able "physical rate" will be 54Mb/s but the n standard lowers guard interval and increases spatial streams (MIMO)to get the higher rates. From memory on a single antenna and 20mhz channel 70Mb/s ish will be the most you will get. Change to 40mhz channel an 150Mb/s should be doable, having bluetooth running will knock this down though. To get the 600Mb/s you will need 4 antennas and 40Mhz channel width.

Comment: I think your answer could be a little more clear, and maybe requires a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try turning power save off

- `sudo su`
- `cp /etc/network/interfaces interfaces.bak`
- `echo "post-up iwconfig wlan0 power off" >> /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: ive made a roundup of solutions to fix different wifi adapters on raspberry pi 1/2/3/zero https://nwgat.ninja/fixing-raspberry-pi-network-issues/

Comment: @wiak thanks those are helpful.  One recommendation: change your `sudo echo [whatever] > /etc/[whatever]` to `echo [whatever] | sudo tee -a /etc/[whatever]`.  `sudo echo` doesn't actually allow you to write to a non-user-writable file.  So _pipe_ it to a sudo'ed `tee` instead of _redirecting_ it to a write-locked file.